# ssrs date compare with specific month

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

[image: Report layout]

I want to compare my `Fields!Date.Value` with month December-2014. If my `Fields!Date.Value` = "any date of December " where my `Fields!Bilable.Value` is "YES" and check if its company is "SL" then put at "SL" Column 1 and at VSI and VSPL insert 0 or null. if `Fields!Bilable.Value` is null then don't count this row.

For example

Fields!Date.Value is 12/15/2014 and which matches with December-2014 and its "Bilable" is "yes" then it should put at SL column 1 and at VSI an VSPL insert 0.

```
Bilable    Company    Date           December       
                                    SL  VSI VSPL
Yes        SL       12/15/2014          
No         VSPL     12/26/2014      ?   ?    ?
Yes        VSI      1/20/2015           
Yes        SL       1/25/2015           
Yes        VSPL     12/25/2014          
                             Total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SL column, put the following expression:

```
=IIF(Year(Fields!Date.Value) = 2014 AND Month(Fields!Date.Value) = 12 AND Fields!Bilable.Value = "Yes" AND Fields!Company.Value = "SL", 1, 0)
```

For the other two columns do the same but change "SL" to "VSI and "VSPL" as required.

You can also sum on this for your Total row:

```
=SUM(IIF(Year(Fields!Date.Value) = 2014 AND Month(Fields!Date.Value) = 12 AND Fields!Bilable.Value = "Yes" AND Fields!Company.Value = "SL", 1, 0))
```